# Вызов метода при попытке обращения к переменной объекта

Tags: python, ооп, python-3.x

Есть класс:

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.module = (x**2 + y**2) ** 0.5

    def hypotenuse(self):
        return (self.x**2 + self.y**2) ** 0.5
```

Надо что бы при попытке обращения к переменной `module` возвращался результат выполнения метода `hypotenuse`:

```
>>> vector = Vector(3, 4)
>>> vector.module
5
>>> vector.x = 5
>>> vector.y = 12
>>> vector.module
13
```

т.е. значение переменной будет вычисляться заново каждый раз при попытке обращения к ней
P.S. Слышал что-то про декораторы, но толком пока не разобрался

Comment: а зачем такое надо? это как-то не по ООП.

Comment: Почему "property" не ООП?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Думаю вы ищете [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property)

```
class Vector:
    def __init__( self, x, y ):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @property
    def module( self ):
        return (self.x**2 + self.y**2) ** 0.5

v = new Vector(2,2)
print( v.module ) # will be 2.8284271247461903

v.x = 3
print( v.module ) # will be 3.605551275463989
```